# How can increase RAM or reset it?

Tags: transactions, ram

EOSflare.io shows I am using all of the RAM (7.94 KB / 7.95 KB). Now all my transactions are failing.  I assume its because of maxing out the RAM?  If so, when does EOS.IO reset RAM usage or do I need buy RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike CPU and Net bandwidth, RAM doesn't refresh itself. Your RAM is occupied by tables on contracts you interacted with. You could send actions to those contracts which release the used RAM, or you could buy more.

Comment: I'd also like to add that unless the contract allows you to release the RAM used, the RAM will remain allocated.

Comment: I bought more RAM to be able to continue with my transactions. This appears to be one of the protections against DDOS where the abuser will run out of RAM. Not a bad idea. Thanks for your response!