# Releasing your RAM, not caring for pre-existing records

Tags: smart-contract, staking, resources

Say if, I push an action to an existing contract on the EOS main net.

This action creates a record in a table/multi index container with me as the payer in the emplace method.

No other action exists on this contract to destroy this record, leaving me the permanent staker of RAM.

Is there a button for me to press in order to get my RAM out, forfeiting this record allowing it to be destroyed? And if the smart contract owner wanted this record to remain permanent in RAM, would he have to pay the RAM costs himself then?

Comment: There is a similar question: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-can-increase-ram-or-reset-it The answer is you have to send actions to the contract that removes the occupied space.