# How do I add more RAM on existing account?

Tags: smart-contract, block-producer, ram

-All of my EOS is staked for CPU and NET bandwidth, should I un-stake some of it first, and how ?

-What command should I execute with a BP to buy, lets say, 600 EOS worth of RAM on an existing account ?

-Am I going to be able to sell the RAM back for EOS once it is used with the airdrop transaction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing a lot of bidding for eos.names (premium names) and found out quickly that the default 7KB or so RAM that I had was gone!

I used the https://toolkit.genereos.io/tools tools with Scatter to buy RAM using unstaked EOS. And I was able to resume transactions right away.

So what I recommend is as follows:

- Set up Scatter with identity using your EOS main net info (private key)
- Use https://toolkit.genereos.io/tools to buy RAM

Of course, if you are out of EOS, then you should unstake first. It will take 3 days to get them back.

Comment: Thank you, does the RAM burn out forever, or is it re-usable (lets say, for a Dapp) ?

Comment: @DisplayName You can send a transaction to the contract that removes the used RAM if provided by the contract. There is an unanswered question: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/921/releasing-your-ram-not-caring-for-pre-existing-records Follow-up there.