# Where is my RAM currently allocated to?

Tags: ram, ram-allocation

Is there a way I can check where my RAM is currently allocated to / being used for?

And how can I re-use it for other things?

Comment: you want to know physically where is that RAM that is allocated to you .. ?

Comment: No, I want to know what dapp/contract is using it. I own 7.96KBof RAM on my account and 7.08KB is being used. However, I have no clue what it is all used for. I feel like I should have a lot more free RAM. So I want to know what is it currently used for and how can I clear it for other uses?

Comment: There is already question about ram usage and  for more clearity you can visit this blog https://blog.springrole.com/the-mechanics-behind-eosio-ram-allocation-940204bc5b7e

Comment: Thanks Nirdesh, but that article does not have the answer I'm looking for. I don't really understand the technical code bit of the article, but I don't think it has my answer in it as well.

I want to know on what my 7.96KB RAM is spend on right now. Is there an explorer or dapp that shows me that? And second, once I know where it is spend on, can I clear it for another use?

Comment: you can  have look at this question https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-can-increase-ram-or-reset-it

Comment: Yes I already read that one, but I saw no answer as to where I can find what contracts are using my RAM. I know it are contracts that I have interacted with, but I'm looking for a place where I can view them, because I can't remember all the contracts I have interacted with.

Also I read that I could send actions to those contracts which release the used RAM. But it does not explain how I can do that... as you might notice I'm kind of a noob at this :(

Comment: @nickl perhaps you can use https://eosflare.io/ and search for your account to find all previous transactions thus all contracts you've interacted with

Comment: @confused00, thanks but I already tried eosflare. They don't have a filter system or something like that. And going through them manually is to much work as I have many many many transactions.Also as far as I know you can't see in the transactions how much a contract has consumed.

I do find it interesting that it looks like I'm the only one wanting to know what my RAM is being used for...

Comment: you're not the only one; we already had this question [here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/how-can-i-see-where-i-am-using-my-eos-ram) and there's no easy way to do this

Comment: Ah did not found that questions. But thank you for your answers. Guess I have to wait for an easy way.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as of now, there is no easy method of achieving this. One must check all actions sent in the past and look up if any of the contracts that they interacted with use their RAM. To free that RAM, one has to check the ABI of the contract to see if the contract provides any way of freeing up the RAM. Unless they do that, there is no way to free the RAM at the moment.

On the bright side, this service is something that the community can create with the current tech, so it may be just a matter of time until a web app can let you know where your RAM is allocated.

This question has also been asked [here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/how-can-i-see-where-i-am-using-my-eos-ram), but it doesn't have any answers either.

Comment: Any idea why the RAM deltas of all my transactions don't add up to my used RAM? See [How do I calculate my used and total RAM balances?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/how-do-i-calculate-my-used-and-total-ram-balances)